# ImportError: No module named 'bson.objectid'

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, bson, flask-pymongo

from bson.objectid import ObjectId 
,after importing this, I am getting the following error
ImportError: No module named 'bson.objectid'.
This works for me on windows but not on ubuntu ,for the pymongo version 3.5.1

Comment: Did you try reinstalling `pymongo==3.5.1`?

Comment: yes already did that, two times.

Comment: You may be having issues with your python installation. Are you running your script in a virtual environment?